# Tableau Insert Customized Rows of Subtotals

Tags: tableau-api, subtotal

I have a data set with 13 rows, each representing a product type. Those 13 products then divided into 3 groups (an image of the data is attached below),

- the first 7 products are in Group1
- the next 3 products are in Group2
- the last 3 products are in Group3

My task at hand is to insert a row that gives the subtotal of the first 7 products (i.e., Group1 in the table), then another row that gives the subtotal of the first 10 products (i.e., Group 1 & Group 2), and the grand total (i.e., all 3 groups). The first subtotal row should be inserted after Group1, and the second subtotal row should be inserted after Group2.

Any advise of how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

[image: An Image of the Actual Data]

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Format tab of menu bar select totals -> add all subtotals

FORMAT -> TOTALS -> ADD SUBTOTALS.

Comment: Thanks. But this won't work. It will only give subtotals for Group1, Group2, but not Group1&Group2.